# Podio java API how to download an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: podio

I am trying to download an Excel file from Podio space. I get access to space and get the files within space and the using fileAPI .

The problem is with the file that gets downloaded. I am not able to open it with Excel. 
Here is the code:

```
     List <File> aFileList = aFileAPI.getOnSpace(spaceId, null, null);
     for (int i=0; i<aFileList.size(); i++){

         File thisFile = aFileList.get(i);
         MimeType thiFileMimeType = thisFile.getMimetype();
         System.out.println("thisFile = " +thisFile.toString());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getDescription()  =" + thisFile.getDescription());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getName()  =" + thisFile.getName());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getId()  =" + thisFile.getId());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getSize()  =" + thisFile.getSize());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getCreatedOn()  =" + thisFile.getCreatedOn());
         System.out.println("thisFile.getMimetype()  =" + thisFile.getMimetype());                   

         try {

             aFileAPI.downloadFile(thisFile.getId(), new java.io.File("C:/Users/alisa/Desktop/"+ thisFile.getName()), null);

         } 
         catch (IOException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();

         }
```

I think the API is creating the file without regard to MIME and I don't see anywhere to set it. Please help!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors when opening this file with Excel? What happens if you download same file from web browser (can you open it with Excel)?

Comment: Yep no problem when downloading from the browser. File opens just fine. I just don't see anywhere in the FileAPI.downloadFile. To set the MIME which determines how to create a file just in case it is not a regular text file. My guess is that the PODIO developer folks may have missed this I could be wrong though it could be that I am missing something

Comment: So, can you compare files that you downloaded manually (with browser) and the one downloaded with your code? What is the difference between them?

Comment: yep the file downloaded fro web is 15kb while the one dowloaded with API is 22 k indicating that mime is not correct

Comment: Can you have a look on what's inside downloaded file?

Comment: Also, can you please check which version of Java API is used? (And be sure that this fix is there: https://github.com/podio/podio-java/commit/adee445ba22b6dc437998222d53f43c62047cceb#diff-d636f3254504782754c08c38f13a1583)

Comment: Hi I am using the following API

Comment: /*ResourceFactory resourceFactory = new ResourceFactory(new OAuthClientCredentials

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments I saw another Resource factory method utilizing hot port etc. Does that method needs to be used for file download?

Comment: Can you have a look on what's inside downloaded file?   
Also, can you please check which version of Java API is used? (And be sure that this fix is there: https://github.com/podio/podio-java/commit/adee445ba22b6dc437998222d53f43c62047cceb#diff-d636f3254504782754c08c38f13a1583 )